# Build XBMC on wheezy raspbian

Tags: kodi, raspbian-wheezy

I'm trying to build XBMC to use with wheezy by following this [guide](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianXBMC), however I'm unsuccessful, with only errors being returned. Under pisces this was successful. Why am I unable to compile it under wheezy? What does pisces have that is missing in wheezy?

Answer (score 0):

Try this guide:
http://michael.gorven.za.net/raspberrypi/xbmc

it is more easy to follow and shorter than classic method

Comment: I used this one before. Now I want to build my own with some tweaks.